# How to create and store html page from nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js

I wrote the application in node.js which collects data in the MongoDB database. I.e.:

- name: John
- pagename: mypage
- links: [link1, link2, link3]

I need to create static HTML pages with `pagename.mydomainname.com`, put content from variables (name, link1, link2..) inside this HTML pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My name is - name</p>
    <p>My link 1 is - link1</p>
    <p>My link 2 is - link2</p>
    <p>My link 3 is - link3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And store this HTML files on the server in the special folder. How to do it using Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a templating library. One of the easiest to use and most popular templating libraries is called handlebars.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars

With handlebars you define a template, then throw JSON at the template and it spits out the response.

Here's an example given on the npm page:

```
var source = "<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
         "{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
         "<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "name": "Alan", "hometown": "Somewhere, TX",
         "kids": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var result = template(data);
```

> Would render:
>
> Hello, my name is Alan. I am from Somewhere, TX. I have 2 kids:
>
> - Jimmy is 12
> - Sally is 4

The handlebars documentation is good. http://handlebarsjs.com/

There are other templating libs but this is number one.

nunjucks is another good one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nunjucks

And there are others, just search for handlebars alternatives if interested.

Using one of these templating libs, you would write the output data to file using [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

If you want a simpler one that runs from the command line and has file generation built in, try envsub.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/envsub

Comment: Thanks. Read bit about it. And how to store html file on disk?

Comment: fs.writeFile - see edited answer and link to docs or fs.writeFileSync